# MPMoviePlayerViewController Crashes the app when load big video files

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using MPMoviePlayerViewController to play MP4 files. It is running perfectly for small files (eg. 25-30 MB) but while playing large files (~150 MB) it crashes the app.

Below is the code I am using:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController   alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
playerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerViewController];

player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];

[player prepareToPlay];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerInterruptByUser:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:playerViewController.moviePlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:playerViewController.moviePlayer];

[player play];
```

Any suggestions guys/gals.